# Add error message into validation summary from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, validationsummary

I want to add my error message into the Validation Summary from Javascript instead just alert it.
Below is my code for my Javascript.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var counter = 0;            

            $("#addrow").on("click", function () {

                var gv = document.getElementById("<%= myTable.ClientID %>");
                var tb = gv.getElementsByTagName("input");

                for (var i = 0; i < tb.length; i++) {
                    if (tb[i].type == "text") {
                        if (tb[i].value < 0.0625) {
                            alert("Dimensions details cannot be empty!");
                            return false;
                        } 
                    }
                }
                return true;                
            });
        });
    </script>



// And I'm using the asp Validation Summary.
   
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="vsSummary" CssClass="errors" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Group1" ForeColor="Red" />
```

Is it possible to add the error message into the ASP Validation Summary??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can update html using JavaScript/JQuery.

Check dom, there is available hidden label of validation summary.
Update it HTML and make display block.

```
<script>
$("#vsSummary").html("Dimensions details cannot be empty!");
$("#vsSummary").css("display", "block")

</script>
```

for hide validation summary you can use fadeOut()

```
  <script>
            $("#vsSummary").html("Dimensions details cannot be empty!");
            $("#vsSummary").css("display", "block").fadeOut(1000);         
       </script>
```

If you not get validation summary label, than just add hidden label and update it html and display it.
Hope it works in your case.